# How to simplify my two REGEX to one?

Tags: java

The string is like this being assigned to a variable `fromFile`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>

        <span class="test"></span>
       <ruby>
        text1<rp>(</rp><rt>textA</rt><rp>)</rp>
        text2<rp>(</rp><rt>textB</rt><rp>)</rp>
        text3<rp>(</rp><rt>textC</rt><rp>)</rp>
        </ruby>
        <img src="images/aaaaa.jpg">
        <img src="./audio/bbbbb.mp3">
        <img src="../../audio/ccccc.mp3">
        <img class="aaaa">
        <input class="bbbb">
        <audio controls>
            <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my Regular Expressions are:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<rt>(.+?)</rt>)|(?=(\\b(\\w*\\S)\\b)<rp>)");
final Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\b(\\w*\\S)\\b)<rp>)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fromFile);
final Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(fromFile);
```

```
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher2.find();
    fromFile = "<font class=\"ruby\" title=\"" + matcher.group(1) + "\"" + ">" + matcher2.group(1) + "</font>";

    break;
}
if((matcher.find()) != true) {
    System.out.println(fromFile);
}
```

I'd like to make it simply by using only one Regular Expression what will produce the same output.
The first regex will extract the element inside the `<rt></rt>` and the second one will get the data before the tag `<rp>`. I assigned them, the extracted data being found to `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher2.group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regexp to match both the strings on the same line by doing a line by line parsing

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)<rp>.*<rt>(\\S+)<\\/rt>.*");
```

complete code

```
    List<String> lines = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("pathToFile")))) {
        lines = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList()); //File content to List<String>
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)<rp>.*<rt>(\\S+)<\\/rt>.*");
    for (String line : lines) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
```

output

```
text1 textA
text2 textB
text3 textC
```